# Deleting row from recycler view and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete arow from firebase when swiped in the recycler view. I have managed to remove the record from the recycler view but am struggling with deleting it from firebase. The following is what I am currently using, with an error in the adpater in the deleteItem() method (on the getSnapshots() method (Cannot resolve method 'getSnapshots()').

My activity with the Item touch helper for the recycler view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_profile);
 Log.d(TAG, "finding recyclerview");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerBooking);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        Log.d(TAG, "getting db reference");



        //FirebaseSearch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_tz8kbFUsU
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Booking");
        Query firebaseSearchQuery = reference.orderByChild("customerID").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        firebaseSearchQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "populating recyclerview");

                list = new ArrayList<Booking>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Booking b = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Booking.class);
                    list.add(b);
                }
                adapter = new MyAdapterBookings(CustomerProfile.this, list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(CustomerProfile.this, "Opsss.... Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);



        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback1 = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.UP) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                // Row is swiped from recycler view
                // remove it from adapter
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        };

        // attaching the touch helper to recycler view
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback1).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

@Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position) {

        if (viewHolder instanceof MyAdapterBookings.MyViewHolder) {
            // get the removed item name to display it in snack bar
            String name = list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getMuaName();

            // backup of removed item for undo purpose
            final Booking deletedItem = list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            final int deletedIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            // remove the item from recycler view
            adapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            adapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());


            // showing snack bar with Undo option
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Appointment with " + name + " cancelled!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // undo is selected, restore the deleted item
                    adapter.restoreItem(deletedItem, deletedIndex);
                }
            });
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }

    }
```

My adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapterBookings extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterBookings.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Booking> bookings;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    private static final String TAG = "Bookings Adapter";
    public MyAdapterBookings(Context c , ArrayList<Booking> b)
    {
        context = c;
        bookings = b;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bookingview,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(bookings.get(position).getMuaName());
        holder.date.setText(bookings.get(position).getDate());
        holder.time.setText(bookings.get(position).getTime());
        holder.price.setText(bookings.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.location.setText(bookings.get(position).getLocation());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookings.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name,date,time,price,location;
        public RelativeLayout viewBackground, viewForeground;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);

            viewBackground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
            viewForeground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);



        }    }



    public void removeItem(int position) {
        bookings.remove(position);
        // notify the item removed by position
        // to perform recycler view delete animations
        // NOTE: don't call notifyDataSetChanged()
        notifyItemRemoved(position);


}


public void deleteItem(int position){

    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}

public void restoreItem(Booking item, int position) {
        bookings.add(position, item);
        // notify item added by position
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }



}
```

Comment: What is `getSnapshots()` supposed to do?

Comment: Its supposed to get the document reference. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTuhMFP-a1g as it addressed my problem but that line seems to throw errors.

Comment: That tutorial uses an adapter from the [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library, while you seem to be building your own adapter. The `getSnapshot(position)` comes from FirebaseUI. I wrote an answer below on how to do this in your case, which is similar to how FirebaseUI does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a node from the Firebase Realtime Database you need to have a reference to its exact, complete path. You have such references when you're loading the data. For example in the `onDataChange` you *could* delete each node with:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        //Booking b = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Booking.class);
        dataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue();
    }
}
```

Of course that is not what you *want* to do, but it shows how deleting from Firebase works. You need to know the full path of the node you're trying to delete, which including the key of that child node.

In your listener you get the *value* from each child node and add that to a list, that you then display in the adapter. But you're not getting the **key** of each child node. This means that your list/adapter only have part of the knowledge needed to delete the nodes. By the time your `deleteItem` function gets called with the position of the item to delete, there is no way to look up the *key* of that node anymore.

So you need to keep track of both the keys and the values of the child nodes that are in your adapter. A common way to do this is by keeping two lists: one with the keys, and one with the values.

So first you add a `List<String>` for the keys to your adapter:

```
ArrayList<Booking> bookings;
ArrayList<String> keys;
```

And accept that in the adapter's constructor:

```
public MyAdapterBookings(Context c , ArrayList<Booking> b, ArrayList<String> k)
{
    context = c;
    bookings = b;
    keys = k;
}
```

Then you add each key in `onDataChange`:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.d(TAG, "populating recyclerview");

    list = new ArrayList<Booking>();
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Booking b = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Booking.class);
        list.add(b);
        keys.add(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
    }
    adapter = new MyAdapterBookings(CustomerProfile.this, list, keys);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And finally you can then look up the key for the item to delete:

```
public void deleteItem(int position){
    String key = keys.get(position);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Booking");
    ref.child(key).removeValue();
}
```