# when I ask for a user ID,getting error in the code

Tags: android, firebase

In an adapter I want to get the user ID of the selected user.but it shows an error in

> getRef(position)

when getting a key.how to solve that?
This is my OnBindViewHolder,

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;
        final Users current = data.get(position);

        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        myHolder.name.setText(current.getName());
        myHolder.status.setText(current.getStatus());
        Picasso.get().load(current.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.download).into(myHolder.img);

        final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

        View.OnClickListener profileView = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent profile_intent = new Intent(mContext,ProfileActivity.class);
                profile_intent.putExtra("user_id",user_id);
                mContext.startActivity(profile_intent);

            }
        };

        myHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(profileView);
    }
```

I want to take details of the selected users.

This is my ProfileActivity;

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        String user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");

        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);

        mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        mProfileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_display_name);
        mProfileStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_status);
        mProfileFirendsCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_total_friends);
        mSendRequestBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_btn);

        mUsersDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String display_name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                mProfileName.setText(display_name);
                mProfileStatus.setText(status);
            }
```

Comment: `it shows an error` which error?

Comment: a compilation error

Comment: which exactly ?

Comment: compilation failed.cannot find symbol method getRef(int)

Comment: that's because you are trying to use method `getRef` which you did not write. It doesn't know such a method

Comment: so how to solve that?

Comment: that depends on what you want to do, and what you expect this method to do, and which class you are trying to call this mathod in.

Comment: It seems you're trying to use `adapter.getRef(position)`, which is a method that is defined for the [adapters in the FirebaseUI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database) to get the `DatabaseReference` for a certain position. But since you're not using FirebaseUI, you will have to implement it youself. I just showed another developer how to implement that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54959887

Answer (score 1):

Since you need user_id when you select any user, you have to get the adapter position using getAdapterPosition() inside your onClickListener() like this :

```
View.OnClickListener profileView = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String user_id = getRef(getAdapterPosition()).getKey();
            Intent profile_intent = new Intent(mContext,ProfileActivity.class);
            profile_intent.putExtra("user_id",user_id);
            mContext.startActivity(profile_intent);
        }
    };
```