# How can i get firebase child key value when i click on recyclerview item which is pushed to firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When using datasnapshot it deletes all messages but I want to delete  the selected message only, so when I click on recyclerview item which is a message, delete that message from recyclerview as well as from firebase

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference freezerItemsRef = rootRef.child("messages");
        freezerItemsRef.child(freezerItemsRef.getKey()).removeValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: the query you write will delete the all message from the node sir. you need to specify the refernece of that specific message

Comment: i am not getting that message key for refrence

Answer (score 0):

```
    final DatabaseReference deleteChatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.CHATS);

                            deleteChatRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            if (Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.getRef().getKey()).equals(chatRef.get(position))) {
                                                deleteChatRef.child(chatRef.get(position)).removeValue();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
```

> **write this query in on clicklistener of your recycler view just write the path of your database chat node correctly instead of Common.Chat**

Comment: what is chatRef here

Comment: chatRef is the aaraylist of chat model object which is pass in adapter class from the activity

Comment: This is deleting the first message (top message) not the selected message, and when adding keys to list and matching with position and remove does the same

Answer (score 0):

To delete a specific message, you'll need to know the **key** of that message. In Firebase Realtime Database, such keys typically start with `-L...`. So say the user clicked the message with key `-Lasdasd19191`, you can delete the message with:

```
freezerItemsRef.child("-Lasdasd19191").removeValue();
```

To know the key of the message that the user clicked on, you'll typically need to map back from the index/position (which is what Android uses) in the list view that the user clicked on, to the key in the database (which is what Firebase needs). See my longer explanation of that here: [Deleting row from recycler view and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959437/deleting-row-from-recycler-view-and-firebase)